# In the process of spraying liquid from the nozzle, must the pressure at the outlet of the nozzle be equal to the atmospheric pressure?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, compressible-flow, jet

During my studies, with high Mach compressible fluids, I always set the outlet pressure to 1 atm. In that case I can roughly calculate the exit velocity. However, in the case of steady flow, is the outlet pressure still equal to 1 atmosphere? As shown in the picture: Thank you very much[image]

Comment: Are you sure the ambient pressure at the outlet will always be 1atm?

Comment: @SolarMike  I am not sure.

Comment: It is if your dischrge is at sea level at STP.